# How do I access MySQL as a Service on Kubernetes?

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I have the following deployment...

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-data-disk
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql-deployment
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mysql
          image: mysql:5.7
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/var/lib/mysql"
              subPath: "mysql"
              name: mysql-data
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-secrets
                  key: ROOT_PASSWORD
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysql-data-disk
```

This works great I can access the db like this...

```
kubectl exec -it mysql-deployment-<POD-ID> -- /bin/bash
```

Then I run...

```
mysql -u root -h localhost -p
```

And I can log into it. However, when I try to access it as a service by using the following yaml...

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
```

I can see it by running this `kubectl describe service mysql-service` I get...

```
Name:              mysql-service
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                     {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"mysql-service","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[{"port":33...
Selector:          app=mysql
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.101.1.232
Port:              <unset>  3306/TCP
TargetPort:        3306/TCP
Endpoints:         172.17.0.4:3306
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

and I get the ip by running `kubectl cluster-info`

```
#kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.99.100:8443
KubeDNS is running at https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

but when I try to connect using Oracle SQL Developer like this...

[image]

It says it cannot connect.

[image]

How do I connect to the MySQL running on K8s?

Comment: I also tried using the mysql command line locally like "/usr/local/mysql-8.0.16-macos10.14-x86_64/bin/mysql -u root -h 192.168.99.100 -p" but it still didn't work. "ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.99.100' (61)"

Comment: When you add something, update your post ;) ... Did you try to port forward?

Answer (score 3):

Service type `ClusterIP` will not be accessible outside of Pod network. 
If you don't have `LoadBalancer` option, then you have to use either Service type [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-services/) or  [`kubectl port-forward`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/)

Comment: Exposing it externally with no firewall rules is probably a bad plan. The `port-forward` option is safest if this is for introspection and not some kind of permanent connection.

Comment: I tried this... "kubectl port-forward service/mysql-service 3310:3306" but it still fails. "/usr/local/mysql-8.0.16-macos10.14-x86_64/bin/mysql -u root -h 192.168.99.100 --port=3310 -p"

Comment: NM needed to use 127.0.0.1 instead of the cluster IP

Comment: Forwarding a port with kubectl is fairly easy, however, it only works with single Pods and not with Services. https://docs.giantswarm.io/guides/accessing-services-from-the-outside/

Answer (score 1):

1. You need your mysql service to be of Type NodePort instead of ClusterIP to access it outside Kubernetes.
2. Use the Node Port in your client config

Example Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
      nodePort: 30036
      targetPort: 3306
```

So then you can use the port: 30036  in your client.